# Inserting a XIB to a pure OpenGL source code?

Tags: opengl-es

I am having no luck grasping OpenGL ES (this whole concept of setting up my own rendering pipeline, let alone writing a pixel shader, is mind-boggling).

I'm afraid I have to actually use a tutorial code as the foundation for my personal project. The best tutorial and sample code i've seen is from Ray Wenderlich. I know his tutorials link has been mentioned in several posts already.

*** So here's my question(s) ***
Ray's demo/tutorial is a "pure" OpenGL. Im not even sure if thats the right term/concept (is he still using OpenGL ES?). Anyway, i need a way to add some XIB related stuff (like a UIView and a couple of input controls). I hope this is possible with minimal changes. How can I add a UIView and a UIButton to Ray's demo app? (I'd prefer NOT to use the GLKView if possible).

Comment: What kind of problems are you facing? I never had difficulties adding any UIKit controls to my projects and even adding them to the view that uses openGL ES. GLKView is still just an UIView and you can normally add or remove subviews and will act as an overlay.

Comment: Ray's demo doesn't use GLKView. It programmatically adds the window and view thru code. There is no XIB file. Now I suppose i could add all my UI elements thru code as well.

Comment: You could do that or I imagine you can just create your views with XIB and then programmatically add them as subviews. (Though I never ever use XIB)

Answer (score 1):

A programmatically constructed view that presents OpenGL ES content is simply a UIView that uses a CAEAGLLayer for its backing layer instead of a standard CALayer. It's otherwise identical to a normal UIView, so you can add it into a XIB as you would any other view. Add a custom view within Interface Builder and give it a class name matching your OpenGL ES hosting view class name and you're good to go.

You can place this within a view hierarchy anywhere you want, and it will work fine.